# What is the problem here in struct definition and compiler error?

Tags: c, xcode, struct, compiler-errors, initialization

When I type the following code:

```
struct student {
    int* grades;
    int num_grades;
};


int main()
{
    struct student s1 = { { 100, **50**, 74}, 3 }, s2 = { {100, **90**, 80, 90, 90}, 5 }, s3 = { {85, **90**}, 2 };
    struct student arr[3] = { s1, s2, s3 };
}
```

I get two errors error:

```
C2078 too many initializers
E0146 too many initializer values
```

I've marked the numbers with two bold asterisks to tell you where the Visual Studio puts red underline.

Does anyone know why the compiler tells me that error?

Comment: In aggregate initialize the size of the array should be specified and more than the number of elements in initialized list.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot initialize a pointer (`grades` variable) by brace-enclosed initializer list. You need to make use of a [compound literal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_syntax#Compound_literals).

Something like

```
 struct student s1 = { (int []){ 100,  50 , 74}, 3 };
```

should do the job.

Comment: Thanks! it helped!! But you said that char is a different story. Could you give an example with char and how I should define it properly?

Comment: @OmerZohar OK, I was thinking in a different context, sorry. For pointers, you must make use of either compound literal + brace-enclosed list, or, for `char` pointers, you can supply string literals also, like `char * ptr = "Hello";`, instead of `char * ptr = (char []){'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'};`